# Script is reading email as a number instead of string

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm trying to follow this guide (Never programed before):

https://www.groovypost.com/howto/google-sheets-send-email-based-on-cell-value/

But It keeps giving me the error:

Exception: The parameters (number[],String,String) don't match the method signature for MailApp.sendEmail.
sendEmail   @ Send Email.gs:8

For what I understand this means the email value is taking as a number. But I have no idea how to solve this.

```
function sendEmail() {
// Fetch the email address
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Client Input").getRange("D2");
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
// Send Alert Email.
var message = 'Please go to your Issues Tracker for more information'; // Second column
var subject = ' Notification Action Required';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);  
}
```

Comment: It's just telling you that you sending an array to the recipient instead of a string.  `emailRange.getValues()` returns a two dimensional array

Comment: Tell us more about the range and we can  suggest an alternative.[mcve]

Comment: if you intend it two be an array of recipients you might you might get away with `emailRange.getValues().flat().join(',');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `emailRange.getValues()` returns a 2D array you need to reference the actual string value by its indices, which in this case, `[0][0]` as the array has only one value.

```
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues()[0][0];
```

Or if you intend to use one and only one email address, just use:

```
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
```

**References:**

[Class Range | getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

[JavaScript Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Use `var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();` when you only need one value.